# Orbital motion and likelihood of bodies colliding

Tags: homework-and-exercises, orbital-motion, planets

An asteroid is in a highly eccentric elliptical orbit around the sun. The period of the asteroid's orbit is $90$ days. Which of the following statements is true about the possibility between a collision between the asteroid and the Earth?

a.) There is no possibility of a collision

b.) There is a possibility of a collision

c.) There is not enough information provided to determine whether or not there is danger of a collision.

I feel like the answer is (a). Could anybody elaborate for me as to whether or not my assumption is correct and why?

Comment: Is this meant to be in the context of the real physical solar system, or a model where the only bodies are the Sun, Earth and this asteroid?

Comment: I will say the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an easy problem! Hint: From the information given you can calculate the semi-major axis $a$ in Astronomical Units (AU). Do it! Then, of course, at first sight, there is a problem. The eccentricity is not given, so one does not know the aphelion distance $Q$. Nevertheless, one can write down an upper bound on $Q$ in terms of $a$. Write it down! (Drawing an ellipsis may help you!) Finally, check whether this upper bound is good enough to answer the question.

This should definitely help you...

psm